# Create info page for each restaurant with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, info

I am trying to create an info page for each restaurant in a Ruby on rails app. I created an action `info` in `Restaurant controller` and added a line in `routes.rb`. but it gives an error

> "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in RestaurantsController#info" Couldn't
>   find Restaurant with 'id'=..

What is wrong with my code?

This is my Restaurant controller:

```
class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_restaurant, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :info]

  def info
  end 

  private
  def set_restaurant
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id]) 
  end
end
```

This is my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

 resources :restaurants do 
  get '/info', to: 'restaurants#info'
 end

end
```

And this a link to restaurant info page:

```
<%= link_to 'Info', restaurant_info_path(@restaurant) %>
```

Comment: In which page you have this line `<%= link_to 'Info', restaurant_info_path(@restaurant) %>`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! In restaurant show page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in RestaurantsController#info

By having the *custom route* **nested inside** the `resources :restaurants`, generates the route with **wrong keys**. When you run `rake routes`, you can see this route

```
restaurant_info GET  /restaurants/:restaurant_id/info(.:format)  restaurants#info
```

So this route has `:restaurant_id` not `:id`. So you cannot do `params[:id]` to fetch the value here in this line `@restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])` which fails with that error. Changing `params[:id]` to `params[:restaurant_id]` should solve your problem but that is **not** the right solution.

The obvious and the ideal solution would be to tweak your custom route, so it can generated like this

```
 restaurant_info GET  /restaurants/:id/info(.:format)  restaurants#info
```

You can tweak your custom route to below to achieve this and not having that nested inside `resources :restaurants`

```
get 'restaurants/:id/info', to: 'restaurants#info', as: :restaurant_info
resources :restaurants
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help and detailed explanation

Comment: wouldn't better REST routing be 'restaurants/:id/info' ?

Comment: @m.simonborg Thanks for notifying that! I actually forgot to edit it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `set_restaurant` method isn't getting any params, check that and come back if it is receiving them correctly.